# React Native Drawer change color of status bar

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-drawer

I'm using the [React Native Drawer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drawer) package. When using it, the the background color of the iOS status bar is changed to white.

Here is an example of my code:

The demo is available here: https://snack.expo.io/@dennismadsen/react-native-drawer-status-bar-issue

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={ref => (this._drawer = ref)}
        content={<AssetExample />}
        type="overlay"
        styles={drawerStyles}>
        <View>
          <Button
            onPress={this.openControlPanel}
            title="Open drawer"
            color="blue"
          />
        </View>
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
```

[image: White status bar]

How can I fix this and make the background automatically use the grey background from the content area? If I remove the `Drawer` from the render-method the background color of the status bar gets grey as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fragment (from React) and SafeAreaView (from react native) as below:

```
    import React,{Fragment} from 'react';
    import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
    import Constants from 'expo-constants';
    import Drawer, { DrawerStyles } from 'react-native-drawer';

    import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

    export default class App extends React.Component {

      openControlPanel = () => {
        this._drawer.open();
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <Fragment>
           <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 0, backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
           <Drawer
            ref={ref => (this._drawer = ref)}
            content={<AssetExample />}
            type="overlay"
            styles={drawerStyles}>
            <View>
              <Button
                onPress={this.openControlPanel}
                title="Open drawer"
                color="blue"
              />
            </View>
           </Drawer>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
    }

    const drawerStyles: DrawerStyles = {
      drawer: {
        marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
      },
      main: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0',
        marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
      },
    };
```

you can use any color to safeAreaView and it will be apply to status bar.
For more details visit https://medium.com/reactbrasil/react-native-set-different-colors-on-top-and-bottom-in-safeareaview-component-f008823483f3

Answer (score 0):

Because your code gives you a `marginTop` as high as the status height line, it must be white, which is the basic color.

You can remove `style.drawer` and `marginTop`

```js
const drawerStyles: DrawerStyles = {
  main: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0'
  },
};
```